# Tizen login for facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, tizen

Like Android and iOS there is no child browser plugin available for Tizen.

So what process to perform oAuth 2.0 on Tizen for Facebook?

From a Web app we can launch browser on Tizen. Is it possible on Tizen to track the current URL in the browser after launching it?

Answer (score 1):

impossible on tizen 2.0. The only way is use deprecated Facebook REST API to get access token and then use Facebook Graph API. Try sample from here https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/social-network-services-tizen

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to launch the browser. But it is possible to open another window inside in your application with window.open() and monitor the url. Don't worry, the page from your app will be retained.